# Compare model fits of two GAM

Tags: r, statistics, vgam

I have a matrix `Expr` with rows representing variables and columns samples.
I have a categorical vector called `groups` (containing either "A","B", or "C")
I want to test which of variables 'Expr' can be explained by the fact that the sample belong to a `group`.

My strategy would be modelling the problem with a generalized additive model (with a negative binomial distribution).
And then I want use a likelihood ratio test in a variable wise way to get a p value for each variable.
I do:

```
require(VGAM)
m <- vgam(Expr ~ group, family=negbinomial)
m_alternative <- vgam(Expr ~ 1, family=negbinomial)
```

and then:

```
lr <- lrtest(m, m_alternative)
```

The last step is wrong because it is testing the overall likelihood ratio of the two model not the variable wise.
Instead of a single p value I would like to get a vector of the p-values for every variable.

How should I do it?
(I am very new to R, so forgive me my stupidity)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why this isn't working? Or what you expect it to do?

Comment: Basically you're testing if a model with `group` is any better than a model without it. That is an overall test for `group`. It sounds like you are doing what you want.

Comment: @MrFlick usually that is the what one wants to do but what I am trying to do here is a little bit different. I want to test for EVERY variable of Expr if the model with grouping is better than Expr ~ 1  that is basically just the noise. I will use the p-values to determine wich variable is changing between groups

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `Expr` as your predictors It think you may have your formula backwards. The response should be on the left, so I guess that's groups in your case.

If `Expr` is a `data.frame`, you can do regression on all variables with

```
m <- vgam(group ~ ., Expr, family=negbinomial)
```

If `class(Expr)=="matrix"`, then

```
m <- vgam(group ~ Expr, family=negbinomial)
```

probably should work, but you may just get slightly odd looking coefficient labels.